# trigger click IE and Chrome

Tags: jquery, click

is it possible to trigger a click with jQuery that works cross browser?

html:

```
<a id="go-societe" href="#societe" class="societetrigger" >Societe</a>
```

works in firefox but doesn't work in IE and chrome:

```
$('a.societetrigger')[0].click();
```

doesn't work in firefox,  IE and chrome:

```
$('a.societetrigger').click(function(){
    $('a.societetrigger').click();
});
```

Comment: Binding a click event callback which trigger the click event sound ummm interesting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to trigger a click with jQuery that works cross
>   browser?

Yes you just need to use jQuery...

`$('a.societetrigger')[0]` is a DOM element not a jQuery object, thus it won't work, if you want only the first element wrap it with `$()`:

```
$($('a.societetrigger')[0]).click();
```

or use the jQuery `first` function:

```
$('a.societetrigger').first().click();
```

The second code which doesn't work in all the browsers, Attaches callback function to the `click` event which will trigger the click event... Does it sounds reasonable to you? to me it sounds like an **infinite loop**.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling the `click` function on a jQuery object: `$('a.societetrigger')[0]` will return a DOM element.

Try the following:

```
$('a.societetrigger').first().click();
```